# Can't execute the addon on Firefox v.48.0.2

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, jpm

I am developing an extension using Mozilla Firefox add-on SDK I am facing issue while executing the add on using **jpm run** command. It opens the browser window, but it's not showing the context menu or any part of the add-on, and shows the message below in the console:

```
1473775175874   addons.xpi      WARN    Add-on @addOnName is not correctly signed.
1473775175875   addons.xpi      WARN    Add-on @addOnName is not correctly signed.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jpm run does NOT work with Firefox 48, or later](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38887048/jpm-run-does-not-work-with-firefox-48-or-later)

Comment: The [linked duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38903632/3773011) will provide you with both why and the available solutions.